# Есть такой код, можно ли как то объединить id-шники чтобы сократить код. Их там еще больше. Но только в JS

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть такой код, можно ли как то объединить id-шники чтобы сократить код. Их там еще больше. Но только в JS

```
 let showMsg = document.querySelectorAll('#item1, #item2, #item3,#item4, #item5, #item6, 
    #item7 ,#item8, #item10 ,#item10');
    for (let i = 0; i < showMsg.length; i++) {
    let msg = showMsg[i];
    msg.style.display = 'none';}
    document.getElementById('item3').style.display='flex';
```

Comment: Задайте группе элементов класс

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [селектор по атрибуту](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
let showMsg = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="item"]');
```

Comment: Точнее `'[id^="item"]'` т.е. без единицы вконце

Comment: @stckvrw, всё верно. Просто скопировал и не исправил :)

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю, что вам нужно именно по id, но если эти элементы имеют что-то общее, то логичнее было бы дать им и общий класс. И вот уже по этому классу получать элементы.

Пример:

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('item')
console.log(items)
```

```html
<div class="item" id="item1"></div>
<div class="item" id="item2"></div>
<div class="item" id="item3"></div>
<div class="item" id="item4"></div>
<div class="item" id="item5"></div>
<div class="item" id="item6"></div>
```